# Nodejs-Compass,PID,Motors-with johnny-five

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino

I just finish coding this code which use for control robot using compass sensor with PID control to control motors. Trying to make javascript object for necessary job.

Please guide me for a better code.

[Watch Video to get how it works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2K17SGgQ8RY)

I use johnny-five package for control Arduino and pid-controller for PID control.

```
var five = require('johnny-five');
var board = new five.Board();
var motorRight;
var motorLeft;
var compass;

var PID = require('pid-controller');
var heading = 0;
var headingSetpoint = 0;
var Kp = 5;
var Ki = 0;
var Kd = 0;
var ctrl = new PID(heading, headingSetpoint, Kp, Ki, Kd, 'reverse');
board.on('ready', function(){
  motorLeft = new five.Motor({
    pins: {
      pwm: 4,
      dir: 50,
      cdir: 51
    }
  });
  motorRight = new five.Motor({
    pins: {
      pwm: 5,
      dir: 52,
      cdir: 53
    }
  });
  motorUtils = {
    Forward : function(pwm) {
      motorRight.forward(pwm);
      motorLeft.forward(pwm);
    },
    Backward : function(pwm) {
      motorRight.reverse(pwm);
      motorLeft.reverse(pwm);
    },
    RotateLeft : function(pwm) {
      motorRight.forward(pwm);
      motorLeft.reverse(pwm);
    },
    RotateRight : function(pwm) {
      motorRight.reverse(pwm);
      motorLeft.forward(pwm);
    },
    TurnLeft : function(pwm) {
      motorRight.forward(pwm);
      motorLeft.brake();
    },
    TurnRight : function(pwm) {
      motorRight.brake();
      motorLeft.forward(pwm);
    },
    Stop : function() {
      motorRight.brake();
      motorLeft.brake();
    }
  }

  var pidUtils = {
    init : function() {
      ctrl.setPoint(0);
      ctrl.setMode(PID.AUTOMATIC);
      ctrl.setSampleTime(1);
    },
    readCompass : function() {
      return heading;
    },
    pidLoop : function() {
      ctrl.setInput(10 - pidUtils.readCompass());
      ctrl.compute();
      pidUtils.setMotor(ctrl.getOutput());
    },
    setMotor : function(output) {
      //console.log('PID', Math.floor(ctrl.getOutput()) , Math.floor(ctrl.getSetPoint()), ctrl.getInput(), ctrl.getDirection(), heading);
      //Q1 && Q2
      if(ctrl.getSetPoint() >= 0 &&
              ctrl.getSetPoint() < 180){
                console.log('Q1');
        if((180+ctrl.getSetPoint()) > pidUtils.readCompass()){
          console.log('right', output);
          motorUtils.RotateRight(output);
        }
        else if ((180+ctrl.getSetPoint()) < pidUtils.readCompass() ||
                  ctrl.getSetPoint() > pidUtils.readCompass()) {
          console.log('left');
          motorUtils.RotateLeft(ctrl.getOutput());
        }
      }
      //Q3
      else if (ctrl.getSetPoint() > 180 &&
               ctrl.getSetPoint() < 270){
                 console.log('Q3');
         if((180+ctrl.getSetPoint()) > pidUtils.readCompass()){
           motorUtils.RotateRight(ctrl.getOutput());
         }
         else if (ctrl.getSetPoint() > pidUtils.readCompass()) {
           motorUtils.RotateLeft(ctrl.getOutput());
         }
      }
      //Q4
      else if (ctrl.getSetPoint() > 270 &&
               ctrl.getSetPoint() <= 360){
                 console.log('Q4');
         if((180+ctrl.getSetPoint()) > pidUtils.readCompass() ||
             (ctrl.getSetPoint() - 180) > pidUtils.readCompass()){
           motorUtils.RotateRight(ctrl.getOutput());
         }
         else if ((ctrl.getSetPoint() - 180) < pidUtils.readCompass()) {
           motorUtils.RotateLeft(ctrl.getOutput());
         }
      }
    }
  }

  compass= new five.Compass({
    controller: "HMC5883L"
  });

  board.repl.inject({
    motorUtils: motorUtils,
    motorLeft: motorLeft,
    motorRight: motorRight,
    ctrl: ctrl
  });


  compass.on('data', function() {
    heading = this.heading;
  });
  compass.once('data', function(){
    pidUtils.init();
    setInterval(pidUtils.pidLoop, 1);
  });

});
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first question.